Windows Defender detects CVE-2015-0072.C in thunderbird, gmail
I bought a new PC and installed Thunderbird. Ever since then Windows Defender keeps complaining about a dangerous threat "CVE-2015-0072.C". Looking at the details, Windows Defender says it's at "AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\o4dt57h4.default-release\ImapMail\imap.gmail-1.com\INBOX". When I tell it to delete or quarantine it, it just pops up again a couple of minutes later.
2015 sounds old, is this thing still a threat? How would this be on my gmail account and not be detected by google?
Defender also complained once that a steam game I have installed was a trojan, which I find to be unlikely. Maybe there's something going on with Windows Defender?
Anybody know what's going on? How should I proceed?

False positives do happen. That being said, CVE-2015-0072 is an HTML vulnerability in Internet Explorer. It could be present in an message in your Gmail account.

@DanielB Since Windows Defender won't specify which email, is there any way I can stop these constant warnings?
